# Nested For Loops with += Operating Using List Comprehension

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

My code:

```
a = [[random.randint(0,10) for i in range(3)] for j in range(4)]
b = [0]*4
c = [random.random() for i in range(12)]
for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in a[i]:
        b[i] += c[j]
```

Any idea how to implementing this as a list comprehension?

Comment: This is not work, because you can't use list as indices b[i] += j. The variable i is list.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do ?

Comment: @d-coder thanks for your interest. I have edited my question. I want to use list comprehension to replace my for loops.

Comment: Hm.. you will have IndexError in case when j=10, because random.randint returns a random integer N such that a <= N <= b.

Comment: @AlexLisovoy Ah, my bad. Updated it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sum`:

```
b = [sum(row) for row in a]
```

#### edit

```
b = [sum(c[i] for i in row) for row in a]
```

Comment: Thanks for help, Eric. But I am very sorry I did not ask my question exactly. Now I have edited the question, which involves an external list c.

Comment: @user1244186: then `b = [sum(c[i] for i in row) for row in a]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippet:

```
import operator

b = [sum(map(operator.getitem,[c]*3, a_)) for a_ in a]
```

Or with `operator.itemgetter`:

```
b = [sum(operator.itemgetter(*_a)(c)) for _a in a]
```

Comment: `operator.itemgetter(*args)` and `map(f, a1, a2)` are both pretty opaque ways to write this

Comment: Eric's solution seems easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, is this following what you want?

```
import random

a = [[random.randint(0,10) for i in range(4)] for j in range(4)]
b = [0 for i in range(4)]

for i in a:
    for j in i:
        b[a.index(i)] += j

print b
```

Comment: b[a.index(i)] += j should be b[a.index(i)] += c[j]